# ng2-charts not working with angularjs2 webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, ng2-charts

I am trying to use ng2-charts with angularjs 2:

in app.ts :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './shared';
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';
```

my file html :

```
       <canvas baseChart
        [datasets]="barChartData"
        [labels]="barChartLabels"
        [options]="barChartOptions"
        [legend]="barChartLegend"
        [chartType]="barChartType"
        (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
        (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
       </canvas>
```

in webpack.config.js
   alias: {
    'ng2-charts': 'node_modules/ng2-charts'
    }

the error in browser or when execute npm test is :

```
Can't bind to 'datasets' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("

 <canvas baseChart
            [ERROR ->][datasets]="barChartData"
            [labels]="barChartLabels"
            [options]="barChartOption"): AppComponent@10:12
Can't bind to 'labels' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("
 <canvas baseChart
            [datasets]="barChartData"
            [ERROR ->][labels]="barChartLabels"
            [options]="barChartOptions"
            [legend]="barChartLegen"): AppComponent@11:12
Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("
            [datasets]="barChartData"
            [labels]="barChartLabels"
            [ERROR ->][options]="barChartOptions"
            [legend]="barChartLegend"
            [chartType]="barChartTy"): AppComponent@12:12
Can't bind to 'legend' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("
            [labels]="barChartLabels"
            [options]="barChartOptions"
            [ERROR ->][legend]="barChartLegend"
            [chartType]="barChartType"
            (chartHover)="chartHover"): AppComponent@13:12
Can't bind to 'chartType' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("
            [options]="barChartOptions"
            [legend]="barChartLegend"
            [ERROR ->][chartType]="barChartType"
            (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
            (chartClick)=""): AppComponent@14:12 in karma-shim.js (line 12563)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message suggests that `Angular` doesn't recognize `baseChart` as a directive, so when you try to bind to `[datasets]`, it looks for that property on `canvas` instead of `baseChart`.

If I'm right, the fix is to properly import `ChartsModule` into any module that needs it.  Do *not* import it directly into your `AppComponent`

**AppModule**

```
import {NgModule}      from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'; // or CommonModule
import {ChartsModule}  from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';

 // https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#ngmodule-properties
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, ChartsModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ] 
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Once your module's `imports` array contains `ChartsModule`, you will be able to use the chart directives and components without the need to import them into your components.

Comment: Wait, but question was about karma test. having this problem after running ng test. so where I have import ChartsModule in karna ?